# How to force IntelliJ to use pom.xml settings

Tags: java, kotlin, maven, intellij-idea, scalatest

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2 with Apache Maven 3.9.4.
Working on a Java project with some Scala and Kotlin in it. The project is old. Hence the Kotlin version is 1.3.

When running `mvn -f integration-test/pom.xml test-compile scalatest:test` in the terminal everything works fine. But when I try to run the test within IntelliJ like:
[image: Run scala test]

It will show up an error complaining that Kotlin **1.2** is no more supported.

`Kotlin: API version 1.2 is no longer supported; please, use version 1.3 or greater.`

I get that, I would like to upgrade Kotlin but it is out of my scope. It's far down in the backlog. But I need a solution in the meantime.

The Kotlin dependency I use:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-osgi-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

**What I try to achieve in the end?**
I want to be able to run a single test so I can debug the code and figure out whats wrong with the test.

**Concludes to: How can I force IntelliJ to just run the mvn project settings**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what @Sam said, you might also want to check [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#delegate_to_maven) in the documentation, in particular:

> By default, IntelliJ IDEA uses the native IntelliJ IDEA builder to build a Maven project

So I think it's just the built-in compiler that complains about the old version of Kotlin. I think you have 2 options to overcome this issue:

1. Let IntelliJ delegate the build to Maven (as described in the link above)
2. Configure the built-in Kotlin compiler to use an older version of the language. This can be done by changing the settings as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiler-kotlin-compiler.html#kotlin-compiler-common-settings) (under `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Kotlin Compiler`). Depending on the version of IntelliJ + the Kotlin plugin, you might or might not be able to solve the issue this way.

Comment: Your second point was helpful. It seems that I cannot downgrade Kotlin because of the JPS Kotlin Plugin, which itself is depending on a certain IntelliJ version. This means I cannot run Kotlin 1.3 in IntelliJ 2023.2.

Comment: Since this isn't exactly the solution but it pointed me to it I accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: if you install the [Jetbrains Toolbox app](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/), you should be able to install older version of IntelliJ and hence compile Kotlin 1.3. Alternatively, you'll find older IntelliJ versions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I did. The toolbox only the last 3 major versions. For a 2017 version you have to, as described in the link, download it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here:
File - Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Build Tools - Maven - User settings file

Compare that with the result from

```
mvn -X | find "settings"
```

where you can see what settings file you are using when running mvn from your command line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I may have not been precise enough.